# Recorded song in GarageBand and uploaded to iCloud but file now missing from phone

Tags: garageband

Earlier today, I recorded a song and uploaded it to the iCloud.

I want to edit it on my MacBook Air (OS X Mavericks) and then send it back to my iPhone, but the file on my iPhone just disappeared?

Comment: is your file still on iCloud?

Comment: Yes,it is now on my iCloud < but I want to record more tracks on my phone, so I want to get them back...

Comment: so what is preventing you to move it from iCloud to your phone?

Comment: Sorry!! I just couldn't figure out the right STEP to move it back to my iPhone!!

Answer (score 1):

I found some [instructions](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-icloud-with-garageband-for-ios/) that might help you with your problem.

> When you want to send a song to iCloud, tap on the Edit button and
>   select a song (or songs). With iCloud enabled in the app, you will now
>   see an iCloud icon along the top bar. Tapping on the iCloud icon will
>   bring up a prompt, asking if you want to send the song(s) to iCloud.
>
> After the song is uploaded to iCloud, you will see an iCloud logo in
>   the top-right corner of the song thumbnail, indicating a successful
>   upload and the fact that the song is stored in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I did this the other way round. I had a file stored on iCloud. I opened the song in GarageBand and closed it by saving it on my iPhone. Then I selected the file after downloading the file from iCloud and selected "Remove from iCloud". After doing so, I was very disappointed since the music composition was nearly finished ... BUT ... somehow I had an old version on my iPhone after selecting "Remove from iCloud". Nearly have a week of work disappeared. Storing the files on the iPhone memory seems to cause LESS trouble since I always have a security backup every time I connect my iPhone to iTunes to make a backup on my hardisk.

That's a really DISAPPOINTING experience!

PS: And strangely, I wasn't even able to open some files stored on iCloud. Only the first file worked. I had to install three times Garageband from the app store to make it working. A really FRUSTRATING experience!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).   - From Review